# IOS querying Latitude/Longitude / Trignometric functions

Tags: ios, objective-c

I currently use a MSSQL query that allows me to find items that are in a certain radius.
It looks like this :

```
select distinct ID,longitude,latitude,
(@unite * ACOS(cos(radians(@latitude))*cos(radians(latitude))*cos(radians(longitude)
-radians(@longitude))+sin(radians(@latitude))*sin(radians(latitude)))) as distance
from myTable
where (@unite * ACOS(cos(radians(@latitude))*cos(radians(latitude)) *
cos(radians(longitude)-radians(@longitude))+
sin(radians(@latitude))*sin(radians(latitude))))<@radius
```

I would like to know if it's possible to convert this query into Objective C (I use CoreData in my app and I have more than 8 000 records).

Comment: If you have bigger DataBase and want good performance, i will suggest you using sqlite3 instead of core data.

Comment: I have several sounds between coredata and sqlite3 about performance. what I like with coredata it's the tableview management. I don't have to load the data into an array (especially when I have a lot of records)... I m a little bit confuse..

Comment: I cant see why loading data in table view would be a problem. sqlite3 have possibility to extend with C function so it can be pretty fast and effective.

Comment: Ok I Will investigate... :)...

Answer (score 1):

I found an interesting article about my need using sqlite
http://www.thismuchiknow.co.uk/?p=71
Thanks

Comment: If I was helpful it would be nice to give me upvotes to previous answers :)